# TensorFlow and OpenCL

Tags: tensorflow, opencl, tensorboard

It seems [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org) only supports CUDA and not OpenCL.

I saw the [tensorflow-cl](https://github.com/hughperkins/tensorflow-cl) project, which compiles the CUDA code into OpenCL, but it is still a development version which does not work in all cases.

My question is whether Google, TensorFlow's developer, will ever develop a multi-platform version of its tool (no, I do not mean the CPU only version). Are the features of proprietary CUDA so critical to focus on a single GPU vendor? Are there any plans to develop an OpenCL/Vulkan/SPIR-V version at anytime in the future?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for Google, not us.

Comment: Help center: "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" - TensorFlow, OpenCL, CUDA are software libraries, i.e. development tools. My question is related to support among these tools, to make a decision about the path to take in developing my project.

Comment: "My question is whether Google, TensorFlow's developer, will ever develop" is a question that only Google could answer, and is better addressed to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is obviously yes, and Tensorflow started supporting OpenCL SYCL in the last few weeks, still in the master github branch and with few basic kernels. Many other kernels need to be written in the new format and contributions are welcome.